# Permutation analysis of group labels using replacements

Tags: r, statistics, permutation, resampling

I have a dataset of (two groups, replicates). My data is split based on the groups so I have 24 samples in group 1 and 20 samples in group 2. My data has replicates. So each set has 4 replicates, hence I have 6 sets in group 1 and 5 sets in group 2. Hence I have assigned indices to them to make it easier during permutation (indices from 1-11). What I want to do now is a routine permutation analysis to obtain the test statistic. I am using non paramteric method with resampling with replacement.

I am trying to permute the group labels. My null hypothesis is that there is no difference between the mean values between both the groups. My doubt\problem in R coding is that I have to pool the data together and then resample the groups. When I try to do this, I have to make sure I maintain the sample size for respective groups (that is after resampling the group lables, my new dataset should still contain 6 sets (24 samples) in group 1 and 5 sets (20 samples) in group 2. I am unable to achieve the latter.

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: For example, could you show a data frame that has both the data and labels, and give an example of a possible rearrangement?